# How can the contents of a url with a pdf extension be converted to text for parsing in PHP without downloading?

Tags: php, pdf, text

How can the contents of a url with a pdf extension be converted to text for parsing in PHP without downloading?

The only way I've seen how to do this (without junk characters) is to download the file to a server folder and shell an executable that converts the binary to text.

Here are some of the executable libraries I've found:
TET, the text extraction toolkit
xpdf

I would prefer to convert the URL pdf WITHOUT downloading the pdf first (such as opening the binary and then convert).

**Is there a way to do this without downloading the pdf in PHP?**

**What method is recommended for quickest execution time?**

As a quick note, I will be doing about 64 URLS with a pdf extension, and not all of these urls will actually point to a pdf.  In fact, some of these urls may point to an alias html page and not necessarily a pdf file, so the difference will need to be discerned before using a conversion tool.

Comment: Why do you prefer not to download them? It seems like a rather arbitrary restriction, and knowing why might help others give you suggestions.

Comment: It is mainly to stop harddrive access, as I will be going over several thousand pdfs.  It would also cause execution time to bottleneck at the download depending on how large the pdf is.


I believe file_get_contents uses memory and does not access the harddrive.  I need something that would get the pdf contents and convert it to text.

Comment: Do you have control over the set timeout of the server?  If you're planning on going through several thousands at a time there is a good chance that it will take longer than your default timeout.

Comment: Yeah.  I've reset the ini time to about a couple hour, so I shouldn't have to worry about this too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting directly from a `URL` is not practical and would be `very slow` ..  most convertion are done via `command line` and not directly with `PHP` for fast and better result

Sample Conversion using `xpdf` `pdftotext`

Installation (Linux) `apt-get install xpdf`

Sample Code

```
$file = $directory . '/' . $filename;
$fileinfo = pathinfo ( $filename );
$content = "";

// pdt to text
if ($fileinfo ['extension'] == 'pdf') {
    $outpath = preg_replace ( "/\.pdf$/", "", $file ) . ".txt";
    system ( "pdftotext -enc UTF-8 " . escapeshellcmd ( $file ), $ret );
    if ($ret == 0) {
        $content = file_get_contents ( $outpath );
        unlink ( $outpath );
    }
}
```

Comment: First question: Would you explain what $ret is?

Comment: See PHP documentation .. http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php .. it is return argument that is passed from calling the script

Answer (score 0):

I found some source code that took the contents of file_get_contents('url.pdf') and did a rough conversion (and I mean very rough).

Since this seems to be the best there is for doing this conversion in memory, I guess I have no choice but to download the 'url.pdf' first.

Would this code work to download the file?

```
//set to the URL of the file you want to download:
$inPath = "http://somepage.com/hello.jpg";
//set to the local path where the file should be saved:
$outPath = "/usr/local/htdocs/hello.jpg";

$in = fopen($inPath, "rb");
$out = fopen($outPath, "wb");

while ($chunk = fread($in,8192) ) {
fwrite($out, $chunk, 8192);
}

fclose($in);
fclose($out);
```

Comment: I would also recommend adding `unlink($outPath);` after you're done with the conversion, to free up the space.  Or, if you're batching the files create an array with all of the files and then batch unlink them at the end.

Comment: Yeah, basically the steps will be: 1. Download the file. 2. Convert the file to text.  3. Parse the text and hope the conversion was successful on the lines that I want. 4. Delete the file.